# Trying to achieve auto navigation through the model or a walkthrough over the model in viewer3d

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-data-management

I am trying to achieve same thing which is done in this [Video](https://youtu.be/ymXgE4wApj0).
need a implement a walk through which navigates through all the model in the rendered file.
Could someone tell me how its been done or what is it called in autodesk language so that I can find
it out on autodesk documentation and try to implement it.

I read it somewhere where it says it need to be implemented while create the RVT file and then it needs to be rendered is it true ?

A reference to sample or document would be a great help.

Answer (score 2):

it called `getState` and `restoreState` in Autodesk Forge.`getState` give you information about current viewport.
First, get state through `var currentState = viewer.getState({viewport: true})` and save `currentState` somewhere, then you call it through `viewer.restoreState(currentState)` to get viewport you already saved.

Comment: thanks this really helped me was able to do above transitions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done in a couple of ways:

- as Paxton said, you can use the [getState](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getstate-filter)/[restoreState](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#restorestate-viewerstate-filter-immediate) functionality; the "state" includes information such as camera position, IDs of selected objects, IDs of hidden objects, section planes, etc. but these can be filtered out.
- alternatively, you could store the camera info manually (for example, using `viewer.navigation.getPosition()`, `viewer.navigation.getTarget()`, and `viewer.navigation.getCameraUpVector()`), and then transitioning to this camera setup using [setView](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Navigation/#setview-position-target), or using the (undocumented) method `viewer.navigation.setRequestTransition(true, newCameraPos, newCameraTarget)`.

Comment: I was able to get the sates but while restoring I am not able to find a way to show a smooth transition could u please refer me to some code which I can implement ? Also I was not able to find any reference for setRequestTransition, let me know if u have some reference for it too

Comment: The 3rd parameter to the `restoreState` method is an `immediate` flag. If you set it to false, the new camera state should be smoothly transitioned to, e.g., `viewer.restoreState(state, null, false);`.

Comment: Regarding the `setRequestTransition` method, I've no idea why it's not included in the docs. I'll report the issue to the docs team.